# Want to reset counter in bibtex

Tags: bibtex, cross-referencing

This is how it looks for now.

```
\begin{thebibliography}{9}
\subsection*{Digitala källor}
\bibliographystyle{ieetr}
\bibitem{Britannica}
''Monte Carlo method,'' i \textit{Britannica}.
[Online]. Tillgänglig: \href {https://www.britannica.com/science/Monte-Carlo-method}{https://www.britannica.com/science/Monte-Carlo-method}, hämtad: 2020-11-15.

\bibitem{SAS}
S.Erlandsson, "Navigation förr och nu, "\textit{Scandinavian traveler}, [Online]. Aug. 2016. Tillgänglig: \href{https://scandinaviantraveler.com/se/flyg/flygnavigation-forr-och-nu}{https://scandinaviantraveler.com/se/flyg/flygnavigation-forr-och-nu}, Hämtad: 2020-11-15.

\bibitem{Simpleflying}
P. Pande, ''How Aircraft navigated before GPS,'' \textit{Simple Flying}, Aug,11, 2020. [Online]. Tillgänglig: \href{https://simpleflying.com/how-aircraft-navigated-before-gps/}{https://simpleflying.com/how-aircraft-navigated-before-gps/}, Hämtad: 2020-11-15.

\bibitem{Bayesian}
N. Bergman, L- Ljung \& F.Gustafsson, ''Terrain Navigation using Bayesian Statistics,'' Linköpings Universitet, Linköping, Sverige, LiTH-ISY-R-2139, 1999. [Online]. Tillgänglig: \href{http://liu.diva-portal.org/smash/get/diva2:316450/FULLTEXT01.pdf}{http://liu.diva-portal.org/smash/get/diva2:316450/FULLTEXT01.pdf}, Hämtad: 2020-11-15.

\bibitem{Marginalized}
T. Schön, F. Gustafsson \& P. J. Nordlund, ''Marginalized Particle Filters for Mixed Linear/Nonlinear State-Space Models,'' \textit{IEEE Transactions on Signal  Processing}, vol. 53, nr. 7, ss. 2279-2289, Jul. 2005, doi:10.1109/TSP.2005.849151.

\bibitem{Pi}
U. Singh, ''Estimation of the value of pi using Monte Carlo Method and Related Study of Errors,'' \textit{Mathematics in School}, vol.  42, nr. 5, ss. 21-23, Nov. 2013, Tillgänglig:  \href{https://www.academia.edu/1887423/Estimation_of_the_value_of_pi_using_Monte_Carlo_Method_and_Related_Study_of_Errors} {https://www.academia.edu/1887423/Estimation_of_the_value_of_pi_using_Monte_Carlo_Method_and_Related_Study_of_Errors}, Hämtad: 2021-02-26.

\subsection*{Bildkällor}
\setcounter{bibitem}{0}

\bibitem{Bild}
N. Bergman, L- Ljung \& F.Gustafsson, ''Terrain Navigation using Bayesian Statistics,'' Linköpings Universitet, Linköping, Sverige, LiTH-ISY-R-2139, 1999. [Online]. Tillgänglig: \href{http://liu.diva-portal.org/smash/get/diva2:316450/FULLTEXT01.pdf}{http://liu.diva-portal.org/smash/get/diva2:316450/FULLTEXT01.pdf}, Hämtad: 2020-11-15.
\end{thebibliography}
```

And it works great! But I have to divide it in two and reset the cite counter. I tried using `\setcounter` but nothing seems to work. I prefer BIbTeX over `biblatex` and would rather not use that. Is there any way to solve this?

Comment: Note that in this example, where you manually generate the `\bibitems` in `thebibliography`, `\bibliographystyle{ieetr}` does nothing. I would remove it to avoid confusion.

Comment: Instead of writing `\href{<url>}{<url>}` it would be much easier to say just `\url{<url>}`. This also avoids some of the errors you are getting.

Comment: Finally to your question: There is no counter `bibitem`. The counter that is used will depend on code you have not shown us (document class, other bibliography-related packages you load), but generally it is `enumiv`. So you could try replacing `\setcounter{bibitem}{0}` with `\setcounter{enumiv}{0}`.

Comment: One more thing: You seem to be using different types of quotation marks: Your entry `SAS` has `"` while most other entries use `''`. Not quite sure which are the typographically correct quotation marks for Swedish. Also `N. Bergman, L- Ljung \& F.Gustafsson,` seems to have two typos, it should probably be `N. Bergman, L. Ljung \& F. Gustafsson,`

Comment: Wow! Thank you so much dude! Learning LaTeX is so fun when y'all are this nice!